# How to Create a Separate Page for Blog Posts in WordPress

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I,m working on company website, the index.php page will be static to show the information of the company, i want include another page to show the posts(articles) blog.php and the link will be www.site.com/blog but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

index.php is a template in the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), as the fallback template for all requests, while blog.php is not in the hierarchy at all. So creating blog.php won't do anything.

What you need to do is create a Page (in WordPress) called "Blog", and a 'Home' page. Then in Settings > Reading, set "Front page displays" to "a static page", then select the home page for the "Front page' and "Blog" to the "Posts" page.

Refer to the template hierarchy I linked above to see which template file will actually get used for each page.

Comment: As mentioned there i can use home.php to render the blog posts index and index,php will be my static main page, So the post Loop will be written in my home.php or somewhere else ?

Comment: Don't use index.php for the static page. It's the fallback for all other queries, so you shouldn't use it for something so specific. You're better off just creating a custom page template.

Answer (score 0):

Create a page and assign the correct template (over on the right side; you may need to use the Options on the page editor page to display it).

The template you select will depend on the theme; but you should be able to figure it out from the available names.